# Detect if a specific button has been clicked in Android WebView

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I am currently working on an android app. This app consists of a WebView and displays a website which I don't own. (F.e. a WebStore)

The app is supposed to recognize/detect when a user clicks a specific button on this website (f.e a "Buy Product" button). If a user clicks such a button, then the app makes a toast pop up.

I know this will be different for every website, however how would I program the click detection in general? I read a few articles about injecting JavaScript etc, however I dont really understand how this is supposed to work. Is there a way to say: If a user clicks on the button with id=buy_button, then show toast?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: hi did you find the solution ? i need to do same..please let me know

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me provide you a full example. 
For your specific website of http://store.nike.com/ch/de_de/pd/mercurial-superfly-v-tech-craft-2-herren-fussballschuh-fur-normalen-rasen/pid-11229711/pgid-11626158

```
{
    ...

    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webview.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(this), "ButtonRecognizer");

    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            loadEvent(clickListener());
        }

        private void loadEvent(String javascript){
            webview.loadUrl("javascript:"+javascript);
        }

        private String clickListener(){
            return getButtons()+ "for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){\n" +
                    "\tbuttons[i].onclick = function(){ console.log('click worked.'); ButtonRecognizer.boundMethod('button clicked'); };\n" +
                    "}";
        }

        private String getButtons(){
            return "var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('add-to-cart'); console.log(buttons.length + ' buttons');\n";
        }
    });

    webview.loadUrl("http://store.nike.com/ch/de_de/pd/mercurial-superfly-v-tech-cra\u200C\u200Bft-2-herren-fussballschuh-fur-normalen-rasen/pid-11229711/pgid-11626158");

    ...
}


class MyJavaScriptInterface {

    private Context ctx;

    MyJavaScriptInterface(Context ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void boundMethod(String html) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx).setTitle("HTML").setMessage("It worked")
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null).setCancelable(false).create().show();
    }

}
```

That'll change the onClick for the button to what you need.

**For everyone else, it looks like there's either a page-specific issue with getElementById() or an Android issue, but getting the elements by class (getElementsByClassName()) worked as expected.
Furthermore, it might be necessary to replace getElementsByClassName() by getElementsByName() such as for example on this website: https://www.digitec.ch/de/s1/product/lexon-flip-wecker-3522142.
Where you would put getElementsByName('AddProductToCart')**

*Info: the \n and the weird combination of strings inside the clickListener method are set like this, because of the IDE. ( ";" are causing problems inside a string).*

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However it doesnt seem to work. I implemented it the following way: webView.addJavascriptInterface(new Object()
    {
      public void performClick()
      {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CHECKOUT!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
    }, "myBoundJavascriptMethod");

Comment: Furthermore I enabled javascript and set up the whole view accordingly. I changed the element id to buyingtools-add-to-cart-button. Btw, I took http://store.nike.com/ch/de_de/pd/mercurial-superfly-v-tech-craft-2-herren-fussballschuh-fur-normalen-rasen/pid-11229711/pgid-11626158 as example to try it on.

Comment: Oh and this is the error I get: I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null", source:

Comment: try "document.getElementById('buy_button').onclick = myBoundJavascriptMethod" instead, let me know if that works.

Comment: Oh, it looks like you might have had the wrong ID for the HTML button, could you verify that 'buy_button' is actually the element ID?

Comment: Basically the best way to do this is use the Chrome browser, open the inspect console, and try your commands there. Then copy > paste directly into the app.

Comment: <button id="buyingtools-add-to-cart-button" type="submit".. so its buyingtools-add-to-cart-button I suppose?

Comment: Updating my answer with your specific example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128296/discussion-between-cedric-portmann-and-wblaschko).

Comment: I noticed that the problem with trying to get the button using "getElementByID" often occurs because a button is at first disabled.. and later gets enabled after a user interaction. In the mean time the referred element seems to change its value.

Answer (score 6):

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
   view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('buy_button').onclick = function(){alert('my message');}");
}
});
```

This tells your webview that when it is finished loading it needs to execute your custom javascript code. In this case the js code searches the page for element with id "buy button" and sets the onclick handler to alert your message.

If you specifically need to toast then you will need to setup a javascript interface and then call a method on their instead. make sense?

Comment: thanks for your answer, however wblaschko already helped me out. :)

Comment: this works for javascript functions , what if i need call some native methods?