# Kotlin (Android) - How do I post a custom event from one thread and listen for that event in the main thread?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm new to Kotlin and I'm struggling to find a way to broadcast a custom event from within a thread (with data attached) and catching and handling that event in the main thread.

I want to listen for the event from my main activity...

```
package com.example.myapp

import android.Manifest
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.webkit.WebView
import android.webkit.WebViewClient
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var contentWebView: WebView

    @SuppressLint("JavascriptInterface")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        if (supportActionBar != null) {
            supportActionBar?.hide()
        }

        contentWebView = findViewById(R.id.contentWebView)
        contentWebView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        contentWebView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
            override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView, url: String, favicon: Bitmap?) {
                // Page loading started handler
            }

            override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView, url: String) {
                // Page loading finished handler
            }
        }
        contentWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html")
        contentWebView.addJavascriptInterface(InterfaceToast(this), "toast")

        /* configure listener for custom event here */


    }

}
```

And broadcast it from my js interfaces...

```
package com.example.myapp

import android.content.Context
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
import android.widget.Toast

/** Instantiate the interface and set the context  */
class InterfaceToast(private val mContext: Context) {

    /** Show a toast from the web page  */
    @JavascriptInterface
    fun show(toast: String) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        /* trigger custom event with String data attached here */

    }
}
```

I'd be grateful if somebody could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Looks like you want to listen to some event from the webpage loaded into web-view, [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40620708/9701793) can help you

Answer (score 0):

use handlers.. handlers could post your events from your thread to the main thread..

Comment: I'm a new member of stackoverflow so my upvote didn't count but thank you anyway 